# IIS7 Serve same application under different directories

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis-7

I wanna serve my application in ISS to be accessed from many different URL's on my web server.

eg.

http://example.com/test1

http://example.com/test2

Both these URL's get served by the same application.

I do NOT however want to just create new virtual applications to the application, because it stuffs up the user membership roles.  The users and their roles must exist accross the two URL's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default if you do this, it should just work. But keep in mind that you will have two different application domains created in memory. So u may have saved on HDD but memory resources would be doubled up because of the same application being loaded twice. Why not use URL rewriting module and let your application handle the rest. That way you will have one instance of application, on disk and memory and your Membership data as well.

Comment: Thanks for that,  I have looked at using the mod rewrite module and it would work better thanks.  I put in a rule to rewrite the URL but not I am getting a 403 forbidden all the time,  any ideas ?